# Python: On a function that does not return anything

Tags: python, arrays, function

I was solving the [Rotate Array](https://leetcode.com/problems/rotate-array/) leetcode problem:

> Given an array, rotate the array to the right by k steps, where k is non-negative.

I tested the following code on my computer (and it seems to do the required job):

```
nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
k = 3
nums = nums[-k:] + nums[:len(nums)-k]
print(nums)

>> [5,6,7,1,2,3,4]
```

Therefore, I tried the following solution:

```
class Solution:
    def rotate(self, nums: List[int], k: int) -> None:
        nums = nums[-k:] + nums[:len(nums)-k]
```

However, getting the following test case wrong:
[image]

Actually, this test case was tested successfully when I ran without defining any function (which I provided above). Yet, really, it didn't work when I defined a special function to `rotate`. Then, I concluded that I might be doing something wrong when defining the function.

Comment: @S3DEV The problem states: `Do not return anything, modify nums in-place instead.`

Comment: what is the point to add it to a class?

Comment: @balderman It's a default by LeetCode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
nums = nums[-k:] + nums[:len(nums)-k]
```

just *rebinds* the *local* variable `nums`, it does not *mutate* the original object that `nums` was referring to before. Do the following instead:

```
nums[:] = nums[-k:] + nums[:len(nums)-k]
```

Since slice assignment is a mutation on the object referred to by `nums`, the rotation will affect the list object that was passed to the function.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about this syntax. Very helpful!

Comment: @user2390182 what is that syntax ( nums[:] ) saying exactly?

Comment: @2bon2b It is slice notation and creates a shallow copy. See more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation